# Why does Ubuntu 18.04 LTS load default wallpapers before user set wallpaper?

Tags: boot, login, desktop-environments, login-screen, desktop-background

I'm running 18.04 LTS, and I've changed both my desktop wallpaper and the login screen wallpaper to a custom image. However, when I boot my computer, The login screen will load and display the default purple with grid (from Unity? I had Unity installed alongside GNOME but I removed it) before loading my image. Then when I log in to my account, my image is replaced with that default purple fuzzy looking wallpaper for a a few seconds before loading my image again as the desktop wallpaper. Is there any way to change this? Its annoying to have these purple themes load between my image as I would like it to be a smooth boot up and log in. I'm fairly new at Linux, so any help would be appreciated!

Edit: I changed the login screen background by editing the gdm3.css file and using the following in the terminal:

```
sudo -i  
xhost +SI:localuser:lightdm  
su lightdm -s /bin/bash  
gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter draw-user-backgrounds 'true'  
gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter background 'path-to-image'
```

Also, to clarify, I installed the Unity desktop environment alongside the default GNOME in 18.04, but have since deleted it. However, I still get the Unity style log in screen with the background grid and the password entry box to the right rather than the GNOME one with the password entry box in the center of the screen.

My custom image wallpaper **does** display on the login screen, I just get the defaults before it loads. So after grub, I get the default Unity login wallpaper, then my login wallpaper, and then when I log in I get the default GNOME login wallpaper, then my custom image desktop wallpaper.

**UPDATE:** After running the command

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

and changing the display manager to GDM rather than lightdm, the default screen flash of the unity login screen has gone away, however, I still get the fuzzy purple GNOME login screen flash (after typing in my password) between my wallpapers when logging in.

**Changing gdm3.css:** Both /etc/alternatives/gdm3.css and /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gdm3.css were changed to:

```
#lockDialogGroup {
  background: #2c001e url(file:///usr/share/backgrounds/5a4f053d3cac434ada0c1cfda611629a.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center; }
```

The oringinal was:

```
#lockDialogGroup {
  background: #2c001e url(resource:///org/gnome/shell/theme/noise-texture.png);
  background-repeat: repeat; }
```

Comment: @pomsky I changed the login screen wallpaper by editing the CSS file, and using this in the terminal: sudo -i
xhost +SI:localuser:lightdm
su lightdm -s /bin/bash
gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter draw-user-backgrounds 'true'
gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter background 'path-to-image'
exit

Comment: BTW 18.04 has neither Unity nor LightDM by default, so the steps you tried probably didn't change anything at all.

Comment: Can you expand on *"editing the gdm3.css"*. For example show the before and after changing lines. Also state the file name including full path. I've read these instructions in other threads but you may have done something different. Thanks. Also I get flashing screens sometimes too in Ubuntu 16.04 with custom Login wallpaper, Plymouth and custom desktop so it might just be "normal" what you're seeing.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix When editing gdm3.css, I found this section: #lockDialogGroup {
  background: #2c001e url(resource:///org/gnome/shell/theme/noise-texture.png);
  background-repeat: repeat; }  and changed it to:#lockDialogGroup {
  background: #2c001e url(file:///usr/share/backgrounds/5a4f053d3cac434ada0c1cfda611629a.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center; }

Comment: +1 for updating your question with gdm3.css info. However when you run `locate gdm3.css` you get **three** files. **1.** - `/etc/alternatives/gdm3.css` **2.** - `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gdm3.css` **3.** - `/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/gdm3.css` could you update your question to reflect the file you changed?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Both /etc/alternatives/gdm3.css and /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gdm3.css were changed.

Comment: @Santiago I'm half way writing a script based on this article: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GDM#Log-in_screen_background_image It appears you are missing the `glib-compile-resources gnome-shell-theme.gresource.xml` compile step but I won't know for sure until I finish the script and test it.